# android studio emulator doesn't finish launching

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have edited the virtual device and when I run the emulator it doesn't start
it's just like it's [emulator image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0NJ4.png) launching and never run(never finish launching)

Comment: Use x86 system image for creating your avd and it will work with speed

Comment: is it working before or you setting up first time?

Comment: it's the first time

Comment: what is system configuration?

Comment: Intel x86 ِAtom System Image?

Comment: show the message you got.

Comment: API 23 ,CPU x86 , Android 6.0

Comment: I don't get error the emulator start launching and does't finish

Comment: recommended ram for emulator android studio is 8gb here are steps to create https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html
or you can use Genymotion if system configuration is low https://www.genymotion.com/  also you can monitor android studio logcat if any message or error is displayed